# calling function on razor view

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I'm trying to do something very simple here.  Apologies new to MVC and Razor
This is on the Razor View Page (.cshtml).
Why is the ShowMessage function is not firing on the button click

Also would the code for the functions ideally be placed here or in the cshtml.cs file?
I managed to call a method in the cshtml.cs file but I couldnt display an alert box to inform the end user about a success or a failure so now I'm trying this way with ViewBag.

```
    @page
    @model IndexModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Air Menu page";

        @functions
        {
          public void ShowMessage()
                {        
                    string output = "Hello";
                    ViewBag.Message(output);                  
                }
    }
}

<form asp-page-handler="showmessage" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Show Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, why don't you call it with an `Action("method", "controller", "params")` ?

Comment: Where would the controller be in a razor .netcore project in VS2017 I can't see it?

Comment: Are you using Core or MVC

Comment: core with razor pages

Comment: See, shouldn't you be using a method `Async Task<IActionResult> OnPostshowmessageAsync()` in your IndexModel ? And i think your button should trigger a submit action.

Comment: yes you can use async (or not) - not sure if its preferred practice.  Some say "if you got then use it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use ViewData or possibly ViewBag

```
public void  OnGetStartKodi()
            {

                int exitcode = 0;
                if (exitcode == 1)
                {
                    ViewData["output"] = exitcode;
                      return Page();                
            }
                else ViewData["output"] = "failed try again exitcode:" + exitcode;               
                  return Page();


            }
```

AND 
fetch from Razor page using

```
 @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("output"))
    {

        <script>alert("@ViewData["output"]")</script>

    }
```